# Allow for canceling starting a bounty within 15 minutes

Tags: feature-request, bounties

I'd like to suggest the following, a member can simply un-do putting a question for a bounty within 10-15 minutes?

Comment: Why would that be needed? You already need to go through a gazillion popups to set one up, with a final confirmation IIRC. Surely the user is well aware of what he/she is doing after all that?

Comment: @Mat - looks like he regrets starting bounty on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158094/how-to-get-the-value-of-bitrate-from-a-wireless-device-driver). Anyway, if you have **valid reason** to cancel the bounty you can flag the question for moderator attention and explain. Moderator can cancel an active bounty. Otherwise, I agree with Mat's comment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. It is simply a bad idea. It can be used to grab people's attention, then re-claim while people rush over to answer the question. Even if no one answers it at first, the question will get extra free attention this way.

Answer (score 5):

Are you asking the ability to re-get a bounty back after 10-15 minutes you set it? I'm not sure it's a good idea. I agree with the other users because:

1. If you set a bounty and then remove it after 10-15 minutes, you basically wasted people's time. I mean those users who came to answer your question in order to get the bounty have just  done it "for nothing", that would be "tricking people". That wouldn't be really honest.
2. There are some passages you have to go through in order to set a bounty, it's not a like a  single-button operation. If you set it, you must be sure of what you're doing it.